# Is it ok for services to reference one another?

Tags: design-patterns, .net, services

I have a service that needs information implemented by another service in the same layer. Is it good practice for one service to take a dependency on another service in the same layer?

Comment: I would think that the best practice is to extract the part that's used in both web services, and have both services use that.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes. I have seen architectural diagrams of SOA (Service Oriented Architecture) where exactly this happens. A service should be written in such a way that it doesn't care if user is calling it, a service in the 'same layer', or it is being combined into a composite service.

The Open Group SOA Reference Architecture diagram shows services calling services in the 'same layer': Figure 22-2 (http://pubs.opengroup.org/architecture/togaf91-doc/arch/chap22.html)

The Open Service Integration Maturity Model (OSIMM) has a good diagram if you search for it. There used to be a good write up from Kim Clark and Brian Petrini but IBM have annoyingly taken down the 'old' content ([original link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0904_clark/0904_clark.html), [wayback machine as it was but no images](https://web.archive.org/web/20120302222832/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0904_clark/0904_clark.html), [low res version but most likely to stay up](https://www.opengroup.org/soa/source-book/osimmv2/p2.htm), [University of Vienna](https://cewebs.cs.univie.ac.at/topics/MaturityModels/index.php?m=D&t=info&c=show&CEWebS_what=Open%7E32%7EGroup%7E32%7EService%7E32%7EIntegration%7E32%7EMaturity%7E32%7EModel))

Answer (score 3):

I use my services within each other. This way I am able to reuse my service methods, instead of copying algorithms all over the layer.

In my experience, one thing to be aware of is **circular dependency**.

1. When initializing a service class, say in the constructor, initializing other service object fields may lead to never ending circular calling if the field also depends on the initializing service.
2. When calling a method, a service method may call another service call and that may also call another service method which can lead to circular call again.

Answer (score -2):

you could use "chain of responsibility" design pattern to achieve this.

http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/ChainOfResponsibility.aspx